# Find the numbers of solutions of the equation $x^k = 1$ and the number of elements of order $k$ in the group $C_{180}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I've been struggling for a while so I ask your help. I sort of have the ''tools'' but I don't know how to apply them. Aside of that I'm not sure if I'm understanding the exercise correctly.

> Find the numbers of solutions of the equation $x^k = 1$ and the number
>   of elements of order $k$ in the group $C_{180}$ with:
>
> $a)$ $k = 7$.
>
> $b)$ $k = 36$.

As far as I understand the solutions of $x^k = 1$ would be all the generators in $C_{180}$.

**THE FIRST PART**

> Find the numbers of solutions of the equation $x^k = 1$ in the cyclic
>   group $C_{180}$

An element $x^k$ is a generator of $C_{180}$ iff $\mathrm{gcd}(n,k) = 1$. 
So the total number of solutions to this equation for $n = 180$ is

\begin{align}
\phi(180) &= \phi(3^22^25)\\
&=\phi(3^2)\phi(2^2)\phi(5)\\
&= (3^2-3)(2^2-2)(5-1)\\
&=72
\end{align}

**SECOND PART**

> Find the number of elements of order $k$ in the group $C_{180}$.

Honestly I don't know how to proceed. Anyway, below I write some thoughts:

$(\ast)$ For $k = 7$.

Here I'm confused. In one hand we have that $\gcd(180,7) = 1$, so $x^7$ is a generator in $C_{180}$, and $|x^7| = \frac{180}{\gcd(180,7)} = 180$. What does this mean?

$(\ast)$ For $k = 36$.

I took a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2060998/count-elements-in-a-cyclic-group-of-given-order) post. According to the most voted answer, since $36|180$ we have that there are $\phi(36) = 12$ elements, but I'm not able to understand why.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: In your attempt for the first part, you found the number of generators. But what you want to find is the number of solutions to $x^k = 1$ for some fixed $k$ which is given in parts (a) and (b). So for example, in part (a) you want to find how many elements satisfy $x^7 = 1$ in $C_{180}$.

Comment: @PratyushSarkar So for $k = 7$, we have that $\mathrm{gcd}(180,7) = 1 \implies x^7$ is a generator in $C_{180}$ with order  $|x^7| = \frac{180}{\mathrm{gcd}(180,7) } = 180$. That implies that $x^7 = x^0 = 1$. Does it mean that there is just one element of order $k = 7$ in $C_{180}$?

Comment: @PratyushSarkar Mmm maybe the number of solutions to the equation with $k = 7$ is $\phi(7) = 6$. I don't understand the difference between number of solutions and number of element for some fixed $k$.

Comment: Here, $x$ is not any specific element in the group. In order to avoid confusion, lets say $C_{180} = \langle a \rangle$ where $a$ is some generator. Then you want to find which elements $a^j$ satisfy the equation $x^7 = 1$, i.e., for which $j$ is it true that $(a^j)^k = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** (Or try to search about this theorem)

If $G$ is a cyclic group of order $n$ and $d$ **is a divisor of n**, then the number of elements of $G$ of order $d$ is $$\varphi(d)$$
where $\varphi$ denotes the Euler's totient function.

So for the first part, $x^k=1$ iff $|x|$ divides $k$. So you have to find the number of elements with order **dividing k**.

For the second part, you have to find the number of elements with order **equal to k**.

The theorem stated can indeed be applied on both parts of question.